# Variance of a transformed uniform random variable

Tags: probability, time-series

Given a sequence of random variables $(Z_t)_{t\in\mathbb{Z}}$ defined as $Z_t = \cos(tu)$ where $u \sim \text{Uniform}(0,2\pi)$. I want to calculate the mean, covariance and variance to show that this is a White noise process which is not strictly stationary. I have calculated the mean and variance in the following way: The cumulative dist function is given by
$$
F_{Z_t}(z) = P(Z_t \leq z) = P(\cos(tu) \leq z) = \frac{\cos^{-1}(z)}{2\pi t}.
$$
Then the density is given by $f_{z_t}(z) = \frac{1}{2 \pi t \sqrt{1-z^2}}$ by using the derivate of the arccos. Thus for the mean we get
\begin{align}
EZ_t &= \int^1_{-1} z f_{Z_t}(z)dz = \frac{1}{2 \pi t} \int^1_{-1} \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\\
&= -\frac{1}{2(2 \pi t)} \int^1_{-1} -\frac{2z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz = -\frac{1}{2(2 \pi t)} \left[\sqrt{1-z^2}\right]^1_{-1} = 0.
\end{align}

Now for the variance I already know that it should be $\text{Var}(Z_t)=\frac{1}{2}$. But I get the following:
\begin{align}
\text{Var}(Z_t) &= EZ_t^2 = \int_{-1}^1 z^2 f_{Z_t}(z)dz = \int_{-1}^1 \frac{z^2}{2\pi t \sqrt{1-z^2}}dz \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi t} \int^1_{-1} \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz = \frac{1}{4t}
\end{align}
As $\int^1_{-1} \frac{z^2}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Where am I going wrong and how does it get independent of $t$?

Is there any easy way to derive the covariance for some $Z_t$ and $Z_j$ with $t\neq j$? Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1. First of all why do you think that the variance should not depend on $t$ ? 2. The covariance calculation is not correct as the $Z_t$ and $Z_j$ are not independent. In fact you can calculate the covariance function and check whether it depends only on $(j-t)$. If it is not, then it is not even Wide Sense Stationary, so strict sense would definitely not hold.

Comment: I know that for this $Z_t$ for all $t \in \mathbb{Z}$ the mean is 0, variance is 1/2 and the covariance is 0. This example of a White noise process is used to prove that a there exists a white noise process that is not strictly stationary. These results can be easily found. Yet the derivation of the variance and covariance I cannot find and am trying to compute myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your mistake is that the cosine is not invertible in $(0,2\pi)$ so that your density formula is wrong. Anyway, your problem can be solved a lot easier:

Let $U \sim U[0,2\pi]$, then it follows:

$$ \mathbb E [Z_t] = \mathbb E[\cos(tU)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} cos(tu) du =0 $$

$$ 
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb E[Z_t^2] &=  \mathbb E[\cos^2(tU)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^2(tu) du \\
                 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 + \cos(2tu)}{2} du \\
                 &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2}du = \frac{1}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Finally for $t \neq s$:

$$ E[Z_t Z_s] =  \mathbb E[\cos(tU)\cos(sU)] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \cos(tu)\cos(su) du =0 $$

The final equality can be shown e.g. by two repeated applications of partial integration.

Comment: Thanks alot. I didn't notice I could write out the expectation in alot cleaner way. The density of the uniform distribution is of course $\frac{1}{2\pi}$

Comment: Oh this factor is just the density of U, i.e.$\mathbb E[\cos(tU)]= \int cos(tu)d \mathbb P_U = \int_{0}^{2\pi} cos(tu) f_U(u) du$, where $f_U$ is the Lebesgue density of $U$.

Comment: One more comment for people trying to calculate the covariance without PI. We can actually use $\cos(\alpha x)\cos(\beta x) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos((\alpha -\beta)x) + \cos(\alpha +\beta)x)\right)$. We then easily obtain that it is zero.